# How can I get a heatmap of count of every buckets by PromQL in grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have the following metrics:
At timepoint t

```
raft_log_lag_count_bucket{type="applied_index",le="200"} 40
raft_log_lag_count_bucket{type="applied_index",le="205"} 64905
raft_log_lag_count_bucket{type="applied_index",le="210"} 119979
```

At timepoint t+1

```
raft_log_lag_count_bucket{type="applied_index",le="200"} 40
raft_log_lag_count_bucket{type="applied_index",le="205"} 67916
raft_log_lag_count_bucket{type="applied_index",le="210"} 125487
```

So between timepoint t and t+1, `raft_log_lag_count_bucket{le="200"}` is increased by 0, while `raft_log_lag_count_bucket{le="205"}` is increased by 67916-64905=3011.

Now I want to generate a heatmap in grafana, whose X axis is timeline, and Y axis is from 0 to inf. The cell at c = (x, y) shows at timepoint x, there are c hits of bucket le=y. For example, (t+1, 205) is 3011.

I wrote the following PromQL

```
sum(delta(raft_log_lag_count_bucket{type=~"applied_index"}[1m])) by (le)
```

However, it gives me the following picture. It is just wrong, since there are many negative values in Y axis, it is very curious.
[image]

I wonder what's wrong here.

Comment: It suits your corners reseted couple minutes before midnight. Have you tried using `increase` instead of `delta`? It has built in processing of counter resets.

Comment: Also, you probably should use `[$__interval]`. More information on topic: https://grafana.com/blog/2020/06/23/how-to-visualize-prometheus-histograms-in-grafana/